# How can i open in app sms composer view in ionic 2

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

How can i open in app sms composer view in ios and android, i have checked ionic native tutorial we need to create custom view to compose and send sms.

i have tried `sms:12345678` it works fine on ios only but open sms app as new. on android it giving error.

below code can send sms from app but user need to add his number

```
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';

constructor(private sms: SMS) { }


...


// Send a text message using default options
this.sms.send('416123456', 'Hello world!');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need `options` object. - [source](http://www.tomislavstankovic.com/blog/ionic-3-sms/)

```
sendSMSfunction(){
          var options = {
            replaceLineBreaks: false,
            android: {
              intent: '' 
            }
        }
        this.sms.send('416123456', 'Hello world!', options);
      }
```

> Set to "INTENT" to send SMS with the native android SMS messaging.
>   Leaving it empty will send the SMS without opening any app. (optional)

Comment: I'm glad that things are working smoothly. If my answer has helped you to solve this please mark it as accepted.